# How to properly change the image of a button I just clicked?

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Here is my dilemma. I have a set of 10 buttons that I use to rate something. They have a star image that when pressed gets changed from a grey one to a red one. If I press the star number 5 all the previous ones also get changed to red.

My problem is that the star that is clicked does not change its image so I found a workaround to introduce a pause inside a dispatcher block. I don't see this very elegant but it works and I was wondering if someone has a better approach.

Even if nobody finds a better way at least this code will help other people to do stuff with multiple buttons that do almost the same thing or browsing through controls in a panel.

Here is the code of the click event:

```
private void btnStar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //First we get the number of the star from the control name
        String strNum = (sender as Button).Name;
        strNum = strNum.Replace("btnStar", "");
        int idxSelected = int.Parse(strNum);

        Debug.WriteLine("Selected star #" + strNum);

        //We store the image ON an OFF to be used later
        ImageBrush imgbrON = new ImageBrush();
        imgbrON.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/estrella_on.png", UriKind.Relative));
        imgbrON.Stretch = Stretch.None;

        ImageBrush imgbrOFF = new ImageBrush();
        imgbrOFF.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/estrella_off.png", UriKind.Relative));
        imgbrOFF.Stretch = Stretch.None;

        //If we pressed the first star when only the first was selected we reset all
        if (idxSelected == 1 && iCurrentNumberOfStars == 1)
        {
            idxSelected = 0; //In order to deselect all stars
            Debug.WriteLine("Deselect all");
        }
        else
        {
            //Here is the code to do the WORKAROUND to select the clicked star
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
           {
               Thread.Sleep(500);
               (sender as Button).Background = imgbrON;
           });
        }

        iCurrentNumberOfStars = idxSelected;


        foreach (UIElement child in ContentPanel.Children)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            if (child.GetType().Name == "Button")
            {
                Button tmpButton = (child as Button);
                Image content = tmpButton.Content as Image;

                strNum = tmpButton.Name;
                if (strNum.StartsWith("btnStar") == true)
                {
                    strNum = strNum.Replace("btnStar", "");
                    int idxtmp = int.Parse(strNum);

                    if (idxtmp > idxSelected )
                    {                       
                        Debug.WriteLine(tmpButton.Name + ":OFF");
                        tmpButton.Background = imgbrOFF;
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        Debug.WriteLine(tmpButton.Name +":ON");
                        tmpButton.Background = imgbrON;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's happens - Button has a visual states which manipulate the background property. When you try to set the background to your own - animation overrides your changes. If you remove background animation from visual states - it will work without a Delay.